# How to get and filter URL parameter

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, filter

I would like to ask if how can I get and put the URL parameters of name, start date and End date under event and set it on a filter. Assuming this is the URL for the name . http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?name=johndrake and for the start date same as the link events.json/start_date_from=2015-01-01 .Can anybody have suggestions? Help me guys.It’s my 1 week trial and error

```
Code be like:

     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
<head>
    <title>project  43</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);

  myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){

  $http.get("http://staging.sample.com/events.json", {headers: {Authorization:  'vuNYhXbpKfH7dxks'}})

    .success(function(response) {
      debugger

     $scope.members=response.events;
     $scope.totals = response.paging;

    });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="tableCtrl">


    <table border="5">
   <tr>
    <th>Event</th>
     <th>Account Shop</th>
     <th>Place</th>
     <th>Activity</th>
   </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
    <td>

    {{member.Event.name}}<br>  <!--names-->
    {{member.Event.id}}<br>
    {{member.Event.date_start}}<br>   <!--start date-->
    {{member.Event.date_end}}<br>     <!--end date-->


    <td>
    {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
    {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
    {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
    </td>

    <td >
    <div ng-repeat="Place in member.Place">
    {{Place.id}}<br>
    {{Place.name}}<br>
    {{Place.lk_country_code}}<br>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td>
    <div ng-repeat="Activity in member.Activity">
    {{Activity.id}}<br>
    {{Activity.short_description}}
    </div>

    </td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for headers ,you can use " $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='vuNYhXbpKfH7dxks' " instead of send the same headers every time.
and you can send the data as a object
{
  name:'johndrake',
  start_date_from:'2015-01-01'
}
post the data,they will become" ?name=johndrake&start_date_from=2015-01-01 "

Comment: where will am i going to put the  $http.defaults.headers.common? because if i will going to remove the http.get the table will not run, because im using API in my events.json ,, and if that so how can i put it on a filter , can you prove it? this is my 1 week nightmare lol , 1 week trial and error , im running out of time ,